# Covid 19 rapid test possible errors from waiting too long to read?

Tags: covid-19, sars-cov-2

What are the error modes of waiting too long to read a rapid antigen test?  Does this increase the probability of the user reading a false positive, false negative, or both?  How does this depend on time?

I currently am interested in results from a BinaxNOW kit, but I've used several brands and they all work more or less the same way, so I suspect that this generalizes.

What is the relationship between test failure modes and time after the recommended reading interval?

Comment: As you know, prior research is required here, so what has your research revealed so far? And please spell out what you mean by $t$. Acronyms, non-obvious abbreviations, and technical jargon should always be spelled out on first use.

Comment: Everything I've found simply describes results after the given time interval as "invalid".

Comment: The tests are only validated for the given time interval, so the answer is "no one knows". In theory, if the antibody is not specific enough, giving it longer time to pick up "false antigens" would increase the false-positive rate. But the answer is probably that no one bothered checking. This is why the testing procedures are standardised

Comment: @Narusan "the answer is 'no one knows'" this is a valid answer to this question.  I would upvote this if you were to post it as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Can someone help me improve this question?  It seems to be on-topic: "diagnostic and prognostic methods."  I would include any information I've found on the matter in my research but my research hasn't turned up any information.  How can I make this question appropriate for this site?

Comment: The problem isn't that it's inappropriate for this site. It _is_ on topic, as you pointed out. The trouble is that in medicine there are many questions that can't be answered, or at least not without a very deep dive into very complex research that requires someone with a specific background to answer. Just to make sure this isn't an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), let me ask what your motivation is for this question. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: In my experience, every single test that I've taken has kept the same readouts for at least 24 hours after the read window has expired. That is, if I check it at the recommended 15 minute mark and at 24 hours + 15 minutes, the test still shows the same result.

Comment: @CareyGregory I am currently trying to solve a problem for which the answer is / would have been "take another test".  However, I am curious on behalf of others who might one day find themselves in a similar predicament about the problem as posted - My personal forgetfulness and laziness causes me to suspect that I'm not the first and won't be the last person to wait a bit too long and then  a last-minute trip to CVS.

Comment: So, basically, you're looking for confirmation of your desired outcome? I think @Narusan had the correct answer in his comment.

Comment: @CareyGregory Not sure why the hostility.  If you don't like the question, then close it.  You have the diamond.  If you'll notice, I encouraged Narusan to post their comment as an answer.

Comment: Huh? That wasn't hostility. Sorry if it came across that way. I just think you're searching for something because you want it to exist but it probably doesn't. The only thing I don't like about your question is that you completely ignored my first comment.

Comment: @CareyGregory I forgot to at you in my response - it's my first comment (+ my first edit).  In all seriousness, though, I'm a scientist, and IMHO knowledge is an end, not a means.  I had an issue in my daily life that made me curious about a thing, and the curiosity became its own telos at that time.  I googled around, didn't find any info at all and then asked here half expecting the answer to be (and perfectly comfortable with the possibility of it being) "nobody knows".